# Hibernate Second Level Cache and Hudson

Tags: java, hibernate, hudson, ehcache, second-level-cache

I'm using SecondLevelCache with hibernate. This is my xml configuration file:

```
    <persistence-unit name="EntityTestHibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_NAME"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="USERNAME"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="PASSWORD"/>            
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>             
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider" />
```

My ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache name="cacheTest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache  name="entityCache" 
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="50"
            eternal="false"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"         
    />
</ehcache>
```

and on my entity there is an annotation like this

```
@Cache(region="entityCache", usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE )
```

When i run locally my UnitTest i have no problems. All tests passed, but if i run tests on my Hudson continuos integretion i have following error (problem is same if i set or not annotation on it @DirtiesContext):

```
>     javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> The cacheTest Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)    at
> org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1167)
>   at
> org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:673)
>   at
> org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:641)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The cacheTest Cache is not alive
> (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)     at
> net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.regions.EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.remove(EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.java:164)
>   at
> net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.strategy.AbstractEhcacheAccessStrategy.evict(AbstractEhcacheAccessStrategy.java:119)
>   at
> net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.evict(NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:96)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:144)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:62)
>   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireRefresh(SessionImpl.java:1118)
>   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.refresh(SessionImpl.java:1098)    at
> org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:666)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The cacheTest Cache is
> not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)   at
> net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:3946)  at
> net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2664)     at
> net.sf.ehcache.Cache.removeInternal(Cache.java:2288)  at
> net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:2207)  at
> net.sf.ehcache.Cache.remove(Cache.java:2125)  at
> net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.regions.EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.remove(EhcacheTransactionalDataRegion.java:160)
```

How could i solve that problem?
Why that happens only on Hudson?

---

### UPDATE

As suggested by @lanimall i have:

- disabled all nodes on Hudson;
- modified persistence.xml.

Replacing

```
< property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider" />
```

with

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
```

but that doesn't solve my problem (but it's a good starting :-)...error is same).

My **environment configuration** is hibernate3 and ehcache-2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution!

In my persistence.xml i had 2 persistence-unit configured as Singleton and in some tests were used both. In that way those share EhCacheSingleton.

Then happens that when EntityFactory associated to one of that was shutdown, consequently make a ehcache shutdown that was used by the other one (because there is one instance of Singleton shared between those 2 entity manager).

Many thanks to @lanimall to open my mind!

Answer (score 2):

what version of hibernate are you using? and Ehcache?
I think what could be happening is that hudson is running on some application server (such as Glassfish, Tomcat 5, JBoss, Jetty 6, etc) and it might have either some ehcache or hibernate lib versions that are competing with the ones you're embedding in your app...hence the problem happening only when running tests in hudson. Make sure to look into that...

Also, per ehcache/hibernate documentation (http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate#Configure-Ehcache-as-the-Second-Level-Cache-Provider), please try to use the "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" setting as opposed to the "hibernate.cache.provider_class"...

And I also usually use the singleton factory (otherwise your JUNIT tests will not work...). Based on hibernate version, use 
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

or (for hibernate 4.x and above)

hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

hope that helps...

Comment: As suggested by you i have: **disabled all nodes on Hudson** ;  **modified persistence.xml** replacing `<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider" />` with    `<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />`; but that doesn't solve my problem (but it's a good starting :-)...error is same). My environment configuration is hibernate3 and ehcache-2.7.2

Comment: interesting...and you're running hudson on what app server?

Comment: it really seems like something in hudson is shutting down (wrongly) the cachemanager...and now i'm thinking about it more, the singleton factory for hudson testing is probably not the right one to use...as hudson might be shutting the cache manager at the end of each tests...and if you use singleton, then it means the instance stays shutdown thereafter? I would try the non-singleton factory: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory.

Comment: AppServer is Tomcat 6. I had thought too that Hudson each test  make cache shutdown but this behavior should be the same locally. Obviously with this other configuration (EHCacheRegioFactory) problem is: `Another CacheManager with same name 'cacheTest' already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following: [junit] 1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary [junit] 2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.`

Answer (score 0):

JUnit share Spring context for speed. I've avoid from this exception when remove explicitly Spring context closing in one of my test.